# Android Studio switch statement on ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

I am trying to use a switch statement on ImageView and assign a String value, so that in my onClick function, I can do some function depending on which ImageView is clicked and use the String value depending on the ImageView clicked. Sorry for the bad explanation, below is the code sample.

ChooseLevelActivity.java

```
public class ChooseLevelActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView level001, level002, level003, level004, level005;
    String level_selected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_level);

        level001 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level001);
        level002 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level002);
        level003 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level003);
        level004 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level004);
        level005 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level005);

        // Array of ImageView
        final ImageView[] levelsArray = {level001, level002, level003, level004, level005};

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            levelsArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        /* Switch statement to change the value of String level_selected
         * depending on which ImageView is clicked.
         * but an error "Constant expression required" shows up
         * What am I missing? How to use the switch on ImageView ?
         */
        switch (v) {
            case level001:
                level_selected = "level001";
                break;
            case level002:
                level_selected = "level002";
                break;
        }

        // Some function that uses the String level_selected

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't use the `id` of the View, which is already constant,  instead of comparing the v itself?

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.level001:
        level_selected = "level001";
         break;
    case R.id.level002:
         level_selected = "level002";
         break;
}
```